# Why is $f(x)$ not a variable? (first order logic)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I started to learn first-order logic and I am confused with the sentence below:

> It is wrong to say "For all y in range of a function f, P(y) holds" as $\forall f(x)[P(f(x))]$ . It is because f(x) is not a variable.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), the word "variable" appears out of nowhere and I could not figure out why $f(x)$ cannot be a variable.

My idea is that if we say "$\forall f(x)$" then $f(x)$ will be considered as a symbol without meaning rather than "value of a function $f$".

Apologies for bad grammars, as I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Because *variables* are the symbol: $x,y,z,\ldots$ while we have the more general concept of *tertm*: either a variable, a constant or a "complex" term built with function symbols, like e.g. $f(x), g(x,y), \ldots$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of [First-Order Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax) (also Wiki's one) starts with the definition of the *syntax*: alphabet, formula, etc.

(Individual) *variables* are part of the *alphabet*:

> "An infinite set of variables, often denoted by lowercase letters at the end of the alphabet $x,y,z,\ldots$"

An expression like $f(x)$ is a *term*; terms are: either (individual) variables, or constants, or built using function symbols.

FOL is called "first-order" because w can only quantify over individual variables: $∀x(x=x)$.

In [Second- (and Higher-) order](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) we can quantify also over predicate and function symbols: $∀f \varphi(f)$.

Answer (score 2):

"Variable" is a vague term in everyday mathematics, but has a *rigorous* definition in mathematical logic, e.g. in first order logic. There one fixes a set $\mathcal V$ of *variables*. The elements of that set are usually single symbols like $x,y,...$ and then these are the variables, and nothing else. In particular, $f(x)$ is not a variable $-$ never!

First order logic further is very percise about how symbols can be arranged, and one rule is that after the $\forall$-symbol, there always comes a variable, and nothing else.

So, while your way two write $\forall f(x)[P(f(x))]$ would be a nice abbreviation of

$$\forall x[x\in\mathrm{Dom}(f)\to P(f(x))]\qquad\text{or}\qquad \forall x[x\in\mathrm{Cod}(f)\to P(x)],$$

it is not standard and therefore should not be used without further explanation.